# Duplicate inference rules

Tags: makefile, ocaml

There are several inference rules in my `makefile` as follows:

```
%.ml: %.mll
    $(OCAMLLEX) $*.mll
%.ml %.mli: %.mly
    $(OCAMLYACC) $*.mly
%.cmo: %.ml %.cmi
    $(OCAMLC) $(OCAMLFLAGS) -c $*.ml
%.cmx: %.ml %.cmi
    $(OCAMLOPT) $(OCAMLFLAGS) -c $*.ml
%.cmi: %.mli
    $(OCAMLC) $(OCAMLFLAGS) -c $*.mli
%.cmo: %.ml
    $(OCAMLC) $(OCAMLFLAGS) -c $*.ml
%.cmx: %.ml
    $(OCAMLOPT) $(OCAMLFLAGS) -c $*.ml
```

I am just wondering if there are duplicates over there. For example, there are two rules for `%.cmx`, which rule counts? Should `.cmx` depends on `.cmi`?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not an expert in `make`, but as far as I understand, if `make` finds a rule with all prerequisite satisfied, it will use it. So your rule with cmi will not be taken at all.

As for ocaml part of the question, `cmx`, should depend on `cmi` if there exists an `mli`, if it doesn't then it is not a failure, and ocaml will not check the module interface. And it is not an easy task, to express this in make language.

I would suggest you either to use an existing Makefile solution, or use `ocamlbuild`, or even `oasis`. I actually have a strong opinion against reinventing the build system. First of all you're spending your precious time on a task, that is already solved. Second, your solution will stil lag behind the existing one, mostly due to the lack of testing and total effort. There are so many wrongly packed ocaml packages, and all of the use their custom and bugy build system. Don't reinvent a bicycle, just learn how to ride :)